# Iteration over "zipped" tuples (for_each_in_tuples)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++17

I want to implement `for_each_in_tuples` that takes a functor and one or more tuples of the same `size` and applies this functor to `i`'th elements of each tuple for `i = 0, ..., size - 1`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple t1(1, 2.2, false);
std::tuple t2(3.3, 'a', 888);

std::cout << std::boolalpha;
for_each_in_tuples(
    [](auto a1, auto a2)
    {
        std::cout << a1 << ' ' << a2 << '\n';
    }, t1, t2);

// Outputs:
// 1 3.3
// 2.2 a
// false 888
```

Implementation:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

namespace impl
{
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct First { using Type = T; };

template<typename... Ts>
using First_t = typename First<Ts...>::Type;

template<auto value, auto... values>
inline constexpr auto all_same = (... && (value == values));

template<class Tuple>
inline constexpr auto tuple_size = std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>;

template<std::size_t index = 0, class Function, class... Tuples>
constexpr void for_each_in_tuples(Function func, Tuples&&... tuples)
{
    constexpr auto size = tuple_size<First_t<Tuples...>>;

    func(std::get<index>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples))...);
    if constexpr (index + 1 < size)
        for_each_in_tuples<index + 1>(func, std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...);
}
}

template<class Function, class... Tuples>
constexpr void for_each_in_tuples(Function func, Tuples&&... tuples)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Tuples) > 0);
    static_assert(impl::all_same<impl::tuple_size<Tuples>...>);

    impl::for_each_in_tuples(func, std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...);
}
```

At Compiler explorer: https://godbolt.org/g/cYknQT

Main questions:

1. Is this implementation correct and can it be simplified?
2. Which name is better, `for_each_in_tuple` or `for_each_in_tuples` (or ...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct First { using Type = T; };

template<typename... Ts>
using First_t = typename First<Ts...>::Type;
```

This can be done using [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) in conjunction with `std::tuple`.

```
template <typename... Ts>
using First_t = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
```

---

```
template<auto value, auto... values>
inline constexpr auto all_same = (... && (value == values));
```

For an empty pack, do you really want the value to be undefined?  The default behavior with empty packs are `&&` is considered `true` and `||` is considered `false`.

---

```
static_assert(sizeof...(Tuples) > 0);
```

Instead of failing, maybe try to call the function with 0 arguments and see what happens?

---

```
static_assert(impl::all_same<impl::tuple_size<Tuples>...>);
```

If you want zipped-like behavior, you'll want to zip tuples until one of the tuples has exhausted its elements (min size instead first size).

---

> Is this implementation correct and can it be simplified?

Yes. Use an iterative approach, like sequential expansion, over recursion.

> Which name is better, for_each_in_tuple or for_each_in_tuples (or ...)?

Maybe `for_each_zipped`.  Tuples can be gathered from the signature of the function.

---

If you want to avoid the recursion, use fold expressions, `std::index_sequence`, and `std::make_index_sequence`.

Start with a simple helper to just invoke the function with elements across all the tuples at a specific index.

```
template <std::size_t Index, typename Function, typename... Tuples>
constexpr void invoke_at(Function&& func, Tuples&&... tuples) {
    func(std::get<Index>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples))...);
}
```

Now we need a way to sequentially call it (`invoke_at<0>(args), invoke_at<1>(args), ..., invoke<N>(args)`).  Use fold expressions like you did for `all_same`, but with the comma operator and unary right fold `((invoke_at<N>(args), ...))`.  To generate the `N`s that gets expanded, we use `std::index_sequence`.

```
template <std::size_t... Indices, typename Function, typename... Tuples>
constexpr void apply_sequence(Function&& func,  std::index_sequence<Indices...>, Tuples&&... tuples) {
    (((void)invoke_at<Indices>(std::forward<Function>(func), std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...), ...));
}
```

Finally, write your function that does checks for preconditions, creates the index sequence, and forwards the arguments to the above helper.

```
template <typename Function, typename... Tuples>
constexpr void tuple_for_each(Function&& func, Tuples&&... tuples) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(tuples) > 0, "Must be called with at least one tuple argument");

    constexpr auto min_length = std::min({std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuples>>...});
    if constexpr (min_length != 0) {
        impl::apply_sequence(std::forward<Function>(func),
                             std::make_index_sequence<min_length>{},
                             std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...);
    }
    else {
        func();
    }
}
```

*Note - The expansion has a cast to `void` that disables any overloaded shenanigans abusing the comma operator.*

Answer (score 3):

There's not much I can criticize about your code; as far as I can see, everything seems well thought out and well written.

As to question number 1: Yes, I think your implementation is correct. I also don't think there's much to be simplified; the implementation is pretty concise, and getting rid of the recursion should be impossible until we get `constexpr while` or `constexpr for` (if ever).

As to question 2, I'm much in favor of `for_each_in_tuples`, since you're clearly iterating multiple tuples at once.

If there's anything to improve, I'd say it's `First`. Since parameter packs are "like" lists of types, the name `Head` would fit much better, in my opinion. Also, just as with normal function parameters, I consider it good style to leave unused parameters unnamed, i.e.

```
template <typename T, typename...>
struct Head { using Type = T; };
```

This is really just personal preference, though.

There is, however, at least one real "issue" with your code, which is related to the `func` parameter in `for_each_in_tuples`: Since you're passing `func` around by value, you could cause performance degradation if `func` is not a lightweight function object (such as a lambda capturing some object with expensive copy operations). Furthermore, this pass-by-value semantics also lock the user out from using function objects that don't support copy operations at all, such as, e.g., a lambda capturing anything of a move-only type. To fix this, I suggest you simply `std::move` `func` into each recursive call, which will cover almost all cases (except for expensive-to-move types, but those are quite rare).

Comment: I'm unsure about this but did you miss an *s* in `lock the user out`?

Comment: @yuri No, not really. The meaning doesn't change much, whether it's `lock the user out` or `lock the users out`, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is correct even if Snowhawk did a good job pointing at what could be improved (although I'd say your recursive approach isn't more complex than "sequential expansion").

My main concern would be with the more general design: a function that 1) zips tuples and 2) applies a function over the zipped elements does one thing too many. It should be composed of two functions: one applying the function to a tuple's members (let's say `tuple_for_each`) and one zipping the tuples (let's say `tuples_zip`). That means you can use `tuple_for_each` also in situations when you don't need to zip, and that you can zip tuples also when you don't need to apply a function to the zipped elements.

Moreover, `for_each` is another loss of generality, since it can't be used when you need to recover the result of the function you're applying (you could with lambda capture, but that's a contortion). So, I would advocate for a `tuple_map` function, returning a tuple containing the result of the application in the case where there is one.

`tuple_map` would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Fn, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Ns>
constexpr auto tuple_map_impl(Fn&& fn, std::index_sequence<Ns...>, Tuple&& tuple) {
    // if fn's return type is void, do not return a tuple since it'd be invalid
    using fn_return_type = decltype(fn(std::get<0>(tuple)));
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<fn_return_type, void>)
        (std::forward<Fn>(fn)(std::get<Ns>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))),...);
    else  
        return std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Fn>(fn)(std::get<Ns>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple)))...);
    }

template <typename Fn, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto tuple_map(Fn&& fn, Tuple&& tuple) {
    constexpr auto tsz = std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>;
    // we need to handle the case where tuple size == 0 because we check fn(std::get<0>(tuple)) in tuple_map_impl
    if constexpr (tsz == 0) return std::forward<Tuple>(tuple);
    else return tuple_map_impl(std::forward<Fn>(fn),
                               std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>(),
                               std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));
    }
```

and `tuple_zip` like this:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename... Tuples>
auto zip_tuples_at(Tuples&&... tuples) {
    return std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples))...);
    }

template <typename Tuple, typename... Other_tuples>
constexpr auto indexes() {
    return std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>();
    }

template <std::size_t... Ns, typename... Tuples>
constexpr auto tuples_zip_impl(std::index_sequence<Ns...>, Tuples&&... tuples) {
    return std::make_tuple(zip_tuples_at<Ns>(tuples...)...);
    }

template <typename... Tuples>
constexpr auto tuples_zip(Tuples&&... tuples) {
    return tuples_zip_impl(indexes<Tuples...>(), std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...);
    }
```

We can then compose `zipped_tuples_map` (my suggestion for the name of your function) with those two functions and `std::apply`:

```
template <typename Fn, typename... Tuples>
auto zipped_tuples_map(Fn&& fn, Tuples&&... tuples) {
    return tuple_map([&fn](auto&& zipped_elements) { return std::apply(std::forward<Fn>(fn), zipped_elements); },
                     tuples_zip(std::forward<Tuples>(tuples)...));
    }
```

A link to the complete example: [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kWf0FJJu4sot4wZo).

Comment: The way you implemented `tuple_map_impl` raised a question about what should it return: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51727961/what-should-tuple-map-return