# Differential Evolution

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, c++23

I have a [PR](https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/1062/files) implementing [differential evolution](https://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/%7Eprabhas//teaching/ec/ec2012/storn_price_de.pdf). I'm a bit concerned about the implementation and would like some feedback:

- The class *could* be a free function. However, there are so many parameters, the templates become unwieldy and getting arguments out of order seems so easy. So I split it between constructor and member function call. Is this a good idea?
- One consequence of the split: I had to use the `.template` member function syntax; are people familiar with it?
- I would like this to work with functions taking individual arguments like

```cpp
double foo(double x, double y, double z);
```

but as it stands, I could only get it to work with functions taking in `std::array` or `std::vector`.

- OpenMP does *kinda* feel like the right choice here, but it does introduce a dependency. Should I just use `std::threads`?

I'm currently targeting the newest C++ standard that I can get to compile, so any suggestions requiring C++23 are fine.

Code:

```cpp
/*
 * Copyright Nick Thompson, 2023
 * Use, modification and distribution are subject to the
 * Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file
 * LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */
#ifndef BOOST_MATH_TOOLS_DIFFERENTIAL_EVOLUTION_HPP
#define BOOST_MATH_TOOLS_DIFFERENTIAL_EVOLUTION_HPP
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <cmath>
#if __has_include(<omp.h>)
#include <omp.h>
#endif
#include <random>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace boost::math::tools {

template <class T>
concept subscriptable = requires(const T &c) { c[0]; };

// Storn, R., & Price, K. (1997). Differential evolution–a simple and efficient heuristic for global optimization over
// continuous spaces. Journal of global optimization, 11, 341-359. See:
// https://www.cp.eng.chula.ac.th/~prabhas//teaching/ec/ec2012/storn_price_de.pdf
template <typename BoundsContainer>
  requires subscriptable<BoundsContainer>
class differential_evolution {
public:
  using BoundType = BoundsContainer::value_type;
  using Real = BoundType::value_type;
  differential_evolution(BoundsContainer bounds, Real F = 0.8, Real crossover_ratio = 0.5, size_t NP = 1000,
                         size_t max_generations = 1000)
      : bounds_{bounds}, F_{F}, CR_{crossover_ratio}, NP_{NP}, max_generations_{max_generations} {
    using std::isfinite;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    if (bounds_.size() == 0) {
       oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __func__;
       oss << ": The dimension of the problem cannot be zero.";
       throw std::domain_error(oss.str());
    }
    if (bounds_[0].size() != 2) {
       oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __func__;
       oss << ": Each element of the bounds container must have two elements.";
       throw std::invalid_argument(oss.str());
    }
    for (auto const &bound : bounds_) {
      if (bound[0] > bound[1]) {
        oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __func__;
        oss << ": The upper bound must be ≥ the lower bound, but the upper bound is "
            << bound[1] << " and the lower is " << bound[0] << ".";
        throw std::domain_error(oss.str());
      }
      if (!isfinite(bound[0])) {
        oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __func__;
        oss << ": The lower bound must be finite, but got " << bound[1] << "."; 
        oss << " For infinite bounds, emulate with std::numeric_limits<Real>::lower() or use a standard infinite->finite transform.";
        throw std::domain_error(oss.str());
      }
      if (!isfinite(bound[1])) {
        oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __func__;
        oss << ": The upper bound must be finite, but got " << bound[1] << "."; 
        oss << " For infinite bounds, emulate with std::numeric_limits<Real>::max() or use a standard infinite->finite transform.";
        throw std::domain_error(oss.str());
      }
    }
    if (NP_ < 4) {
      oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __func__;
      oss << ": The population size must be at least 4.";
      throw std::invalid_argument(oss.str());
    }
    if (F_ > Real(2) || F_ <= Real(0)) {
      oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __func__;
      oss << ": F in (0, 2] is required, but got F=" << F << ".";
      throw std::domain_error(oss.str());
    }
    if (max_generations_ < 1) {
       oss << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ":" << __func__;
       oss << ": There must be at least one generation.";
       throw std::invalid_argument(oss.str());
    }
  }

  template <typename ArgumentContainer, class Func, class URBG>
  ArgumentContainer
  minimize(const Func Phi, URBG &g,
           std::atomic<bool> *cancellation =
               nullptr, // a stop_token might be preferable when compiler support is more widespread.
           size_t threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency(),
           std::vector<std::pair<ArgumentContainer, decltype(std::declval<Func>()(std::declval<ArgumentContainer>()))>>
               *queries = nullptr) {
    constexpr bool has_resize = requires(const ArgumentContainer &t) { t.resize(); };
    using ResultType = decltype(std::declval<Func>()(std::declval<ArgumentContainer>()));
    using std::clamp;
    using std::round;
    using Size_t = ArgumentContainer::size_type;
    std::vector<ArgumentContainer> population(NP_);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < population.size(); ++i) {
      if constexpr (has_resize) {
        // Resize it to same size as bounds_:
        population[i].resize(bounds_.size());
      } else {
        // Argument type must be known at compile-time; like std::array:
        assert(population[i].size() == bounds_.size());
      }
    }
    std::vector<ResultType> fitness(NP_);
    using std::uniform_real_distribution;
    uniform_real_distribution<Real> dis(Real(0), Real(1));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < population.size(); ++i) {
      for (Size_t j = 0; j < bounds_.size(); ++j) {
        auto const &bound = bounds_[j];
        population[i][j] = bound[0] + dis(g) * (bound[1] - bound[0]);
      }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fitness.size(); ++i) {
      fitness[i] = Phi(population[i]);
      if (queries) {
        #pragma omp critical
        queries->push_back(std::make_pair(population[i], fitness[i]));
      }
    }

    const size_t dimension = bounds_.size();
    const auto crossover_int = static_cast<decltype(g())>(round((g.max() - g.min()) * static_cast<double>(CR_)));
    std::vector<URBG> generators(threads);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
       generators[i].seed(g());
    }
    for (size_t generation = 0; generation < max_generations_; ++generation) {
      if (cancellation && *cancellation) {
          break;
      }
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads)
      for (size_t i = 0; i < NP_; ++i) {
        #if defined(_OPENMP)
        size_t thread_idx = omp_get_thread_num();
        #else 
        size_t thread_idx = 0;
        #endif
        auto& gen = generators[thread_idx];
        size_t r1, r2, r3;
        do {
          r1 = gen() % NP_;
        } while (r1 == i);
        do {
          r2 = gen() % NP_;
        } while (r2 == i || r2 == r1);
        do {
          r3 = gen() % NP_;
        } while (r3 == i || r3 == r2 || r3 == r1);
        ArgumentContainer trial_vector;
        if constexpr (has_resize) {
          trial_vector.resize(bounds_.size());
        }
        for (size_t j = 0; j < dimension; ++j) {
          // See equation (4) of the reference:
          auto guaranteed_changed_idx = gen() % NP_;
          if (gen() < crossover_int || j == guaranteed_changed_idx) {
            auto tmp = population[r1][j] + F_ * (population[r2][j] - population[r3][j]);
            trial_vector[j] = clamp(tmp, bounds_[j][0], bounds_[j][1]);
          } else {
            trial_vector[j] = population[i][j];
          }
        }
        auto trial_fitness = Phi(trial_vector);
        if (queries) {
          #pragma omp critical
          queries->push_back(std::make_pair(trial_vector, trial_fitness));
        }
 
        if (trial_fitness < fitness[i]) {
          std::swap(population[i], trial_vector);
          fitness[i] = trial_fitness;
        }
      }
    }


    auto it = std::min_element(fitness.begin(), fitness.end());
    auto idx = std::distance(fitness.begin(), it);
    return population[idx];
  }

private:
  BoundsContainer bounds_;
  Real F_;
  Real CR_;
  size_t NP_;
  size_t max_generations_;
};

} // namespace boost::math::tools
#endif
```

Tests:

```cpp
/*
 * Copyright Nick Thompson, 2023
 * Use, modification and distribution are subject to the
 * Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying file
 * LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
 */

#include "math_unit_test.hpp"
#include <random>
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>
#include <boost/math/tools/differential_evolution.hpp>
#ifdef BOOST_HAS_FLOAT128
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
using boost::multiprecision::float128;
#endif

using boost::math::tools::differential_evolution;
using boost::math::constants::two_pi;
using boost::math::constants::e;
using std::cbrt;
using std::sqrt;
using std::cos;
using std::exp;

// Taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization
template<typename Real>
Real ackley(std::array<Real, 2> const & v) {
    Real x = v[0];
    Real y = v[1];
    Real arg1 = -sqrt((x*x+y*y)/2)/5;
    Real arg2 = cos(two_pi<Real>()*x) + cos(two_pi<Real>()*y);
    return -20*exp(arg1) - exp(arg2/2) + 20 + e<Real>();
}


template<class Real>
void test_ackley()
{
    std::vector<std::array<Real, 2>> bounds(2);
    bounds[0] = {-5, 5};
    bounds[1] = {-5, 5};
    auto de = differential_evolution(bounds, 0.9);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
    auto local_minima = de.template minimize<std::array<Real, 2>>(ackley<Real>, gen);
    CHECK_LE(std::abs(local_minima[0]), 10*std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon());
    CHECK_LE(std::abs(local_minima[1]), 10*std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon());
   
    // Works with a lambda:
    auto ack = [](std::array<Real, 2> const & x) { return ackley<Real>(x); };
    local_minima = de.template minimize<std::array<Real, 2>>(ack, gen);
    CHECK_LE(std::abs(local_minima[0]), 10*std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon());
    CHECK_LE(std::abs(local_minima[1]), 10*std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon());
}

template<typename Real>
auto rosenbrock_saddle(std::array<Real, 2> const & v) {
    auto x = v[0];
    auto y = v[1];
    return 100*(x*x - y)*(x*x - y) + (1 - x)*(1-x);
}

template<class Real>
void test_rosenbrock_saddle()
{
    std::vector<std::array<Real, 2>> bounds(2);
    bounds[0] = {-2.048, 2.048};
    bounds[1] = {-2.048, 2.048};
    auto de = differential_evolution(bounds, 0.9);
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937_64 gen(rd());
    auto local_minima = de.template minimize<std::array<Real, 2>>(rosenbrock_saddle<Real>, gen);
    CHECK_ABSOLUTE_ERROR(local_minima[0], Real(1), 10*std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon());
    CHECK_ABSOLUTE_ERROR(local_minima[1], Real(1), 10*std::numeric_limits<Real>::epsilon());
} 

int main()
{
    test_ackley<float>();
    test_ackley<double>();
    test_rosenbrock_saddle<double>();
    return boost::math::test::report_errors();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## About your concerns

> - The class *could* be a free function. However, there are so many parameters, the templates become unwieldy and getting arguments out of order seems so easy. So I split it between constructor and member function call. Is this a good idea?

You can always create a `struct` holding all the parameters needed by the function, and just pass a reference to that struct. Then you can use designated initializers to fill in the parameters in a safe way. Consider:

```
template<typename BoundsContainer, class Func, class URBG>
struct de_minimize_parameters {
    using BoundType = BoundsContainer::value_type;
    using Real = BoundType::value_type;

    BoundsContainer bounds;
    Real F = 0.8;
    …
    const Func Phi;
    URBG &g;
    …
};

template <typename ArgumentContainer, typename Parameters>
auto minimize(const Parameters& parameters) {
    …
    using ResultType = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(parameters.Phi), ArgumentContainer>;
    …
}
…
template<class Real>
void test_ackley()
{
    …
    de_minimize_parameters params = {
        .bounds = bounds,
        .F = 0.9,
        .Phi = ackley<Real>,
        .g = gen,
    };
    …
    auto local_minima = minimize<std::array<Real, 2>>(params);
    …
}
```

> - One consequence of the split: I had to use the `.template` member function syntax; are people familiar with it?

C++ programmers used to writing templates probably are familiar with it. Many compilers will give a useful warning if you forget the `template` keyword here.

> - I would like this to work with functions taking individual arguments like
>
>   ```
>   double foo(double x, double y, double z);
>   ```
>
>   but as it stands, I could only get it to work with functions taking in `std::array` or `std::vector`.

You can make this work by packing the arguments in a [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) and calling the function using [`std::apply()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply). You also might want to change how you pass the bounds then: it should just be two tuples, one for the lower bound and one for the upper bound.

```
template<…>
auto minimize(…) {
    …
    for (size_t i = 0; i < population.size(); ++i) {
        population[i] = gen_sample(lower_bound_, upper_bound_, gen);
    }
    …
    for (size_t i = 0; i < fitness.size(); ++i) {
        fitness[i] = std::apply(Phi, population[i]);
        …
    }
    …
}
…
Real foo(Real x, Real y, Real z) {
    …
}

template<class Real>
void test_foo()
{
    using vec3 = std::tuple<Real, Real, Real>;
    vec3 lower_bound = {-5, -5, -5};
    vec3 upper_bound = {+5, +5, +5};
    …
    auto local_minima = de.template minimize<vec3>(foo<Real>, gen);
    …
}
```

The hard part will be creating `gen_sample()`, which takes two tuples, and has to iterate over them. C++ makes this particularly hard, you have to implement your own helper function that does this, for example like [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201106/iteration-over-zipped-tuples-for-each-in-tuples). If you have that, then you could write `gen_sample()` like so:

```
template<typename Tuple, typename URBG>
auto gen_sample(const Tuple& lower_bound, const Tuple& upper_bound, URBG& g) {
    return tuple_for_each([&](auto lower_bound, auto upper_bound) {
        return std::uniform_real_distribution(lower_bound, upper_bound)(g);
    }, lower_bound, upper_bound);
}
```

> - OpenMP does *kinda* feel like the right choice here, but it does introduce a dependency. Should I just use `std::threads`?

It's not too hard to create your own thread pool and parallelize the loop this way. You could also consider using an existing thread pool implementation from Boost. It's hard for me to answer what you should do here, it depends on your target audience and how portable you want your code to be.

## Avoid requiring the caller to specify the result type of `minimize()`

The bounds already contain enough information to deduce the result type of `minimize()`, so try to use that instead of requiring the caller to pass that in. If you store the bounds as two tuples, it is trivial, as then it will be the same as `BoundType`.

## Use a callback for queries

Your `minimize()` function takes a pointer to a vector of queries. Maybe the caller doesn't want the results in a `std::vector`. Instead of forcing a container type here, consider passing a callback instead, so the caller can decide how to handle and store queries.

## Avoid code duplication

The checks at the start of the constructor have a lot of duplicated code. Try to reduce that by creating a helper function that constructs the error message and then throws an exception of the required type. Note that you can also use [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) to avoid the `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__func__` macros.

Comment: How did you get the `std::invoke_result_t` to work? I get:

```
fatal error: use of alias template 'std::invoke_result_t' requires template arguments
  102 |     using ResultType = std::invoke_result_t(Phi, std::declval<ArgumentContainer>());
```

Comment: Sorry for the noise; I got it. Way better than the grotesque way I was getting the ResultType.